# Provider Hosted App SharePoint 2013 On Premises - "You can't add this app here"

Tags: provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created a provider Hosted App for SharePoint 2013 On Premises. I have hosted my provider hosted app on Azure Server. And Add an app in App Catalog site. But I am not able add it on my site. I found the following message,

[image]

Can you Please help me how can I solve the particular issue.

Comment: Have you set client id and client secret generated from http://<SharePointWebsite>/_layouts/15/AppRegNew.aspx page?

Comment: Yes, I have set both

Comment: Please also check that user have enough  permission to install the app on site?

Comment: App has been added successfully on App catalog site. But when I am going to add that app on my site then I get the following message

Comment: Have you checked "Find out why" link? It may occurs if you have already installed the app before.

Comment: Yes I checked this link. I got following message "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps". And FYI I have installed this app for the first time

Comment: Please check your App Management Service in Central Admin. If its not configured, then configure it properly. Generally, these errors occurs due to App Management Service. Also I am assuming that you have configured  isolated App Domain for Apps.

Comment: OK. I will check that service. Is there any other possibility for this error.

Comment: No. I have posted answer for how to configure service and machine for apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally occurs when App Management Service is not working properly or App domain is not configured properly.

Below are the steps to re-configure the App Management Service:

In order to install an App from the App Store you must setup an isolated App Domain, this is because Apps from the store deploy to their own app domain and run under a separate process from your SharePoint sites. If your SharePoint site uses the DNS alias http://sharepoint.contoso.com you could have `*.apps.contoso.com` as your app domain. I’m going to walk-through the process required to set-up your environment for Apps but at a high level, if you need more details for each step then head on over to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923(v=office.15).aspx).

Follow the steps below to setup your environment for Apps:

1. Start the App Management Service from Services on Server
2. Provision an App Management Service Application (You can use the UI for this)
3. Create a subdomain domain in DNS – e.g. `*.apps.contoso.com`. You can either create a subdomain or a new domain to host your apps. I’ll leave that choice up to you. Make sure that when setting up the subdomain in a multi-server environment you set the FQDN of the target host to be your SharePoint 2013 box.
4. Set your isolated App Domain by running this command:

   `Set-SPAppDomain "apps.contoso.com"`
5. Start the SPSubscriptionSettings Service by running the following PowerShell command:

   `Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"} | Start-SPServiceInstance`
6. Ensure the App Management Service and SPSubscriptionSettings Services are online by running this command:

   `Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"}`
7. Provision a Subscription Settings Service Application (You will need to use PowerShell for this as it can’t be created through the UI). In my example below I am using the same Application Pool I created for the App Management Service Application.

   `$appPool = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool "SharePoint Service AppPool"$appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool
   $appPool –Name "Subscription Settings Service Application" –DatabaseName Settings_Service
   $proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy –ServiceApplication $appSubSvc`
8. Visit the Manage Service Applications page in Central Admin and verify that both the App Management Service App and Subscriptions Settings Service App are provisioned and started.
   [image]
9. The next thing to do is create an App Catalog. This is essentially a Document Library which is hosted within a separate Site Collection. Choose Apps > Manage App Catalog from Central Admin.
10. Select your Web Application and ensure ‘Create a new app catalog site’ is checked and click OK.
11. Fill in the details for your App Catalog Site and click OK to create it.
12. Nearly there! now we need to configure the App URLs. Select configure App URLs in the Apps section of Central Admin. Enter your App domain you setup earlier (apps.contoso.com) and for the App prefix enter ‘app’.
13. **Important** – please note that if you are using Host Headers for your Web Application then you will need to create a new Web Application on port 80 that doesn’t use Host Headers. This Web App must have a root site collection which can be of any template. If you don’t do this then when you try to click on an App you will be met with a 404 error. This is because SharePoint uses the site running on Port 80 to resolve the app url, this must be a SharePoint site so the Default Web Site won’t work.  Once you have created the Web Application and blank Site Collection do an IISRESET just to be sure. For more details on this check out Mirjam’s post [here](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx).
14. Done! your environment is now configured for Apps. Now when you navigate to your Site Collection and browse to the SharePoint Store you will notice that the warning/error message has disappeared. Try downloading the Facebook Integration App and see how you get on.
15. Done!

**Reference:**

- http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/11/enabling-sharepoint-2013-apps/

Comment: I am facing the same issue in SharePoint online. What are the steps required to solve this problem?